# Check if child package is executed only then execute Execute SQL task

Tags: visual-studio-2013, ssis

I have a SSIS package which has for each loop which reads in incoming files and checks if record exists then execute child package, if record does not exists then execute sequence container. all these are happening inside for each loop.
If the record exists then child package inside the for each loop gets executed and I have to  execute sql task specific for this logic and it has to be executed outside the for each loop.
But this execute sql task gets executed after for each loop completes i.e. even if record exists or if the record does not exists.
But i want to execute sql task only if record exists.
How can I do this in SSIS?

Comment: My brain melted a bit. Can you include some form of small schematic of what you want to achieve and how your SSIS package is working now?

Answer (score 0):

If record exists then execute t-SQL using [sp_start_job (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186757.aspx) to run your 'child package' as you call it.